# Last update filter

Tags: nodes, views, services, updating

I'm developing an application that will access Drupal using **services** and one of the parameters used is the **date**, I used the filter `"Content: Updated date (Updated date)"` but instead of giving me just the last is giving me all of the updates, how can I solve it?

Thanks

Comment: What you want to do? your question is not clear

Comment: Instead of giving me just the last update, the service is giving all the updates related. How can I filter it?
Example:
[{"Type":"cat","Updated date":"13/11/2015 - 10:53"},{"Type":"cat","Updated date":"13/11/2015 - 10:52"},{"Type":"dog","Updated date":"13/11/2015 - 09:55"}]

as you can see cat is repeated because there were two updates. If I filtered for the last update it should bring me just one cat and one dog.

Comment: are you using views module?

Comment: Yes I am. That's how I filter it.

Comment: use views_datasource module and contextual filter that provides date to your display. then just get the page using GET method